# fedora dnf install darktable says no packages found

Tags: linux, fedora

I am trying to install darktable in my fedora 25.

dnf install darktable

gives me the error

No package darktable available.
Error: Unable to find a match.

and when I try

```
dnf list | grep -i darktable
```

I get no output.

I have tried activating rpmfusion-free-release and rpmfusion-nonfree-release

What could be the issue?

Thanks
Paddy

Comment: What if you try `sudo dnf clean all` first?

Comment: Already tried that.  Same results.

Comment: That's odd. What do you get with `dnf repolist`?

Comment: I have been having the exact same issue since switching over to 25. It is listed in the GUI package manager which crashes when I try to install Darktable and dnf has never heard of it. I am using my DT on my crufty old Fed 23 box for RAW editing still which is painfully slow.

Comment: This is the output of dnf repolist             
adobe-linux-i386 Adobe Systems Incorporated 
adobe-linux-x86_64 Adobe Systems Incorporated
*fedora                     Fedora 25 - i386
*rpmfusion-free             RPM Fusion for Fedora 25 - Free
*rpmfusion-free-updates     RPM Fusion for Fedora 25 - Free - Updates
*rpmfusion-nonfree          RPM Fusion for Fedora 25 - Nonfree
*rpmfusion-nonfree-updates  RPM Fusion for Fedora 25 - Nonfree - Updates
*updates                    Fedora 25 - i386 - Updates